Wigner representation on excitated states in string theory
In his string theory lectures David Tong argues on why the first excitated states in the lightcone quantization of the closed string have to be massless, but I don't understand his reasoning.
When studying the first excitated states in the light cone quantization of string theory of a closed string we have the transverse states: $$\alpha^i_{-1}\tilde{\alpha}^j_{-1}|p,0\rangle.$$ We now have to find in what representation of the Lorentz group they sit. In section 2.3.2 he says that, in D dimensions, these $\alpha^{i}$ and $\tilde{\alpha}^j$ both transform in the vector representation of $SO(D-2)$ (I guess it makes sense but I don't really understand why) so there are $(D-2)^2$ possible states.
If the string is massive, we can go to its rest frame and study the little group, which in this case is $SO(D-1)$. Tong says that these $(D-2)^2$ states can't fit in a representation of the little group $SO(D-1)$ but he doesn't explain why and then he moves on to the massless case.
Why can't they fit since I can build a representation of any dimension of the $SO(D-1)$ group?

The only $SO(D - 1)$ representation of dimension $(D - 2)^2$ is extremely boring.

These are indeed the things you should think about when interpreting the lightcone spectrum but Tong is being cavalier about the details. He later admits this on page 45.
The level of the $\alpha^i_{-n}$ oscillators $N$ must be equal to the level of the $\tilde{\alpha}^i_{-n}$ oscillators $\tilde{N}$ but beyond this there is no need to consider the interplay between left and right movers. The $\alpha^i_{-n}$ on the left can be sorted into representations of either $SO(D - 1)$ or $SO(D - 2)$ and the same is true of $\tilde{\alpha}^i_{-n}$ on the right independently. Once you have these two representations $R$ and $\tilde{R}$, the states at this level naturally transform in $R \otimes \tilde{R}$ which can be decomposed into irreps by standard algorithms.
So your question boils down to a chiral one: do the $D - 2$ modes $\alpha^i_{-1}$ form a representation of $SO(D - 1)$ or $SO(D - 2)$? Clearly, $SO(D - 2)$ would be more interesting since this would allow $\alpha^i_{-1}$ to be a vector instead of $D - 2$ scalars. But let's do better than this. Before gauge fixing, $\alpha^\mu_{-1}$ is a Fourier mode of $X^\mu(\sigma, \tau)$ which is chosen to be a co-ordinate of $\mathbb{R}^{D - 1, 1}$. This means it is in the vector representation of $SO(D - 1, 1)$ by definition. Algebraically, this can be phrased as
\begin{equation}
[M^{\mu\nu}, \alpha^\rho_{-1}] = \eta^{\mu\rho} \alpha^\nu_{-1} - \eta^{\nu\rho} \alpha^\mu_{-1}
\end{equation}
where the $M^{\mu\nu} = -M^{\nu\mu}$ are generators of infinitesimal Lorentz transformations. Out of these $D(D - 1)/2$ generators, the exercise now is to find the subset of them which preserve the lightcone directions $\alpha^\pm_{-1}$. I.e. the ones which make the above commutator zero for $\rho = +$ and $\rho = -$. The solution will be all $M^{ij}$ where $i$ and $j$ take values between $1$ and $D - 2$. Going back to the Lorentz commutation relations, it is easy to show that the infinitesimal transformations these $M^{ij}$ generate are those of $SO(D - 2)$.
Now that we know to focus on $SO(D - 2)$, it is intuitively clear that the $SO(D - 1, 1)$ vector $\alpha^\mu_{-1}$ transforms as a $SO(D - 2)$ vector when we limit ourselves to rotations orthogonal to the plane spanned by $\alpha^\pm_{-1}$. More formally, the vector is the result of the $SO(D - 1, 1) \to SO(D - 2)$ branching rule.
